# [Gradle][Play] where is compilePlayBinaryScala defined?

Tags: java, gradle, playframework

I'm relatively new to gradle and Play.

I'm working on play project which uses gradle as build system. I'm trying to use build caching for better performance. From build scan, i observe 'compilePlayBinaryScala' is not cacheable and most of the other tasks are dependent on 'compilePlayBinaryScala'. Enabling caching for 'compilePlayBinaryScala' will really scale up the build.

Gradle official docs lists `.*PlayBinary` tasks (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/play_plugin.html)

I could not find explicit task definition for 'compilePlayBinaryScala' or any other `.*PlayBinaryScala` tasks. Where are these tasks defined?

From my research, i could see this file where tasks may be created.But, i'm not sure. https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/de399b5015b19c07d94aa2eabec47709fc719a68/subprojects/platform-play/src/main/java/org/gradle/play/plugins/PlayApplicationPlugin.java#L160

Since i'm newbie Detailed explanation of why its done this way will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The tasks are created in that file, but not at the method you linked to. The tasks are created for each binary in methods like [`createScalaCompileTask`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/de399b5015b19c07d94aa2eabec47709fc719a68/subprojects/platform-play/src/main/java/org/gradle/play/plugins/PlayApplicationPlugin.java#L237-L245), [`createJarTasks`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/de399b5015b19c07d94aa2eabec47709fc719a68/subprojects/platform-play/src/main/java/org/gradle/play/plugins/PlayApplicationPlugin.java#L247-L274), [`createPlayRunTask`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/de399b5015b19c07d94aa2eabec47709fc719a68/subprojects/platform-play/src/main/java/org/gradle/play/plugins/PlayApplicationPlugin.java#L276-L297). The `@Mutate`, `@BinaryTasks`, `@ComponentBinaries are part of something in Gradle called the *rule based model* (also the *software model*). The usage is described in the [Play plugin documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/4.3.1/userguide/play_plugin.html#sec:play_software_model). The Gradle team experimented with this model for a couple years, but ultimately decided against it and it is not officially deprecated (see the blog post [*State and future of the Gradle Software Model*](https://blog.gradle.org/state-and-future-of-the-gradle-software-model).

The type of the `compilePlayBinaryScala` is [`PlatformScalaCompile`](https://docs.gradle.org/4.3.1/javadoc/org/gradle/language/scala/tasks/PlatformScalaCompile.html). This is stated on the documentation, and could also be determined by running `./gradlew model` or adding a task action like that logs the type. The task name of `"compilePlayBinaryScala"` is calculated from several different things that are a part of the plugin. The component name is `"play"`, so the binaries and tasks are generated based on that and the platform that is targeted. The task naming conventions would be more apparent if the plugin supported more than 1 platform (it does not at the time of writing). An example of another plugin that generates tasks based on component names is Gradle's [native support](https://docs.gradle.org/4.3.1/userguide/native_software.html#sec:native_tasks).

It's not worth going into much depth about how the rules-model is structured, but the high level is the first parameter of the method is the subject and can be changed while the rest of the parameters are inputs and are immutable. In the methods linked above, you will notice the first parameter is of type `ModelMap<Task>`. That is the collection of `Task` objects that can be mutated. The flow looks something like this (I'm probably missing something):

- [default component named `"play"` is created in a `ModelMap<PlayApplicationSpec>`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/de399b5015b19c07d94aa2eabec47709fc719a68/subprojects/platform-play/src/main/java/org/gradle/play/plugins/PlayApplicationPlugin.java#L118-L121)
- [only 1 Play component is supported in the `ModelMap<PlayApplicationSpec>`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/de399b5015b19c07d94aa2eabec47709fc719a68/subprojects/platform-play/src/main/java/org/gradle/play/plugins/PlayApplicationPlugin.java#L129-L134)
- [each `PlayPlatformAwareComponentSpecInternal` is validated that the number of target platforms is not more than 1](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/de399b5015b19c07d94aa2eabec47709fc719a68/subprojects/platform-play/src/main/java/org/gradle/play/plugins/PlayApplicationPlugin.java#L136-L141)
- [source sets are created for the `PlayApplicationSpec`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/de399b5015b19c07d94aa2eabec47709fc719a68/subprojects/platform-play/src/main/java/org/gradle/play/plugins/PlayApplicationPlugin.java#L299-L323)
- [a binary is added to `ModelMap<PlayApplicationBinarySpec>` based on the `PlayApplicationSpecInternal`. The name of the generated binary comes from here somewhere](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/de399b5015b19c07d94aa2eabec47709fc719a68/subprojects/platform-play/src/main/java/org/gradle/play/plugins/PlayApplicationPlugin.java#L155-L189)
- [compile tasks are generated by the `ScalaLanguagePlugin`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/de399b5015b19c07d94aa2eabec47709fc719a68/subprojects/language-scala/src/main/java/org/gradle/language/scala/plugins/ScalaLanguagePlugin.java)
- [`PlatformScalaCompile` tasks are mutated to use the compile classpath from the `PlayApplicationBinarySpec`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/de399b5015b19c07d94aa2eabec47709fc719a68/subprojects/platform-play/src/main/java/org/gradle/play/plugins/PlayApplicationPlugin.java#L237-L245)
- some other configuration rules

That's about as much detail I can give you without really digging much further into the `ScalaLanguagePlugin`. The `./gradlew model` will give you a report of where some things come from and may prove helpful, but it also may not because things are are sort of managed between that model and the normal Gradle configuration model.